# SweetHome 3d No longer works on 15.04

Tags: 15.04

I notice that SweetHome 3d no longer opens after upgrading to 15.04. are there any alternatives to this program on Ubuntu? Quite annoyed by this as I have a house design I was working on which I now can't access.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to open Sweethome3d and it locked up partway open. I install sun version of java per some other suggestions but that did not work. I then opened as sweethome3d as root and it started up correctly. I have not figured out what files are keeping from opening as a regular user but at least I can get it to run.